# Create binary blob in JS

Tags: javascript, file, binary, hex, blob

I'm generating a file client-side, I have the data in hexadecimal and just want to let the user download the generated file.

```
var blob = new Blob([hexData], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
console.log(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

The resulting file is a plain-text file containing hex data in ASCII. How can I force the Blob to contain the binary data as is and not as text?

Answer (score 11):

Derived from @Musa's solution above so I cannot take credit, but it's clearer to write this as an answer than my lame comment to his answer.

```
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(hexdata.match(/.{2}/g)
                              .map(e => parseInt(e, 16)));
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
```

Maybe this is easier to understand? I personally think it is clearer.

Comment: The blob first argument has to be an array `new Blob([byteArray], ...);`

Comment: Thanks. Oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Convert you data to a binary array then create a blob from that.

```
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(hexdata.length/2);
for (var x = 0; x < byteArray.length; x++){
    byteArray[x] = parseInt(hexdata.substr(x*2,2), 16);
}
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/15h9o3d5/

Comment: I'd like to suggest a simpler and maybe cleaner (eye of the beholder) way.

`var byteArray = new Uint8Array(hexdata.match(/.{2}/g)
                                              .map(e => parseInt(e, 16)));`

This splits the hex data into two byte hunks, parses them as hex into numbers, then returns an array of these to the Uin8Array constructor.