# How to download pdf on web

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, blob, reportlab

*Important: I use python*.

I use reportlab to create a pdf on the server (flask), and I get a string by methond `str = canvas.getpdfdata()`. I can use`f = open('result.pdf', 'wb')` and `f.write(str)` to save this as pdf.

Now I want to download this pdf on web, but I don't want to create a pdf file on the server, so I send the string to web, and want to use js to the create file and download it.

I tried to use js code like this: (`saveAs` function is in `FileSaver.js`, which can be found on github)

```
var blob = new Blob([{{ str }}], {type: "application/pdf"});
saveAs(blob, "result.pdf");
```

It throws the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, I try to change the string encoding to hex and base64, but it does not help.

Can you help me? Or can you tell me a way to create and download this pdf without creating a file on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As read in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949152/create-binary-blob-in-js) SO question, you need to convert the binary data to an ByteArray first:

```
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(hexdata.length/2);
for (var x = 0; x < byteArray.length; x++){
    byteArray[x] = parseInt(hexdata.substr(x*2,2), 16);
}
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/15h9o3d5/

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036280/base64-representing-pdf-to-blob-javascript?rq=1) question is asking the exact same thing as you.

Comment: really thanks!!! It's my fault, I made a stupid mistake...When web get the server data, it should use `var str = "{{ data }}"`, but I use `var str = {{ data }}`...T_T